# firebase swift tableview doubles when fetching data

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm a newbie in swift programmation.

I'm currently working on an inbox feed for my application. I can fetch my values from firebase and display them in a UITableView easily but my problems come from when I add or delete a child node from firebase.

**MY PROBLEM** : When I'm in my inbox view controller and I receive a new message, my data doubles. Not in my firebase, but in my list.

**WHAT I TRIED** : I tried `list.removeAll()` in my fetchRequests function every time my firebase child values are modified `ref.observe(.value //...)`. Also, when I tried `ref.observe(.childAdded //...)` and I open my inboxViewController, nothing appears.

**MY CODE** :

```
func FetchRequests() {

        self.requestList.removeAll()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Requests")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {

                    let req = Requests()

                    req.from = value["from"] as? String ?? "From unknown"
                    req.name = value["name"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                    req.img = value["img"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                    req.other = value["other"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                    req.type = value["type"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                    req.key = child.key

                    self.requestList.append(req)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableViewRequests.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Requests").child(requestList[indexPath.row].key!)

            let reqType = requestList[indexPath.row].type

            if reqType?.range(of:"Réponse") != nil {
                print("Answer from admin")
                requestList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                ref.removeValue()
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableViewRequests.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

**WHAT I WANT** : Simply to remove the duplication problem, when receiving a new message in my inbox controller.

I'm using swift 4 by the way,
Thanks in advance,
have a good day/evening/night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `observe` to `observeSingleEvent` in `fetch requests` function.

And also after fetch finished, you could add `observe add child` event and receive only new objects.

Comment: Many thanks, I haven't thought of that! It stopped duplicating, thanks again but now, it still doesn't update the tableView when a child is added.. And I've added .childAdded

Answer (score 1):

You should **reload** your **table** **data** after **for** **loop** ends. Just modify your code as below:

```
func FetchRequests() {
    self.requestList.removeAll()
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID!).child("Requests")
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if let value = child.value as? NSDictionary {
                let req = Requests()
                req.from = value["from"] as? String ?? "From unknown"
                req.name = value["name"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                req.img = value["img"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                req.other = value["other"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                req.type = value["type"] as? String ?? "Erreur"
                req.key = child.key
                self.requestList.append(req)          
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableViewRequests.reloadData()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```